only continuing process if target file is a pdf
hello all I'm making a process that will import a list of all the files in a given folder for processing.
hoever I only want the files to go through the process if they are a PDF
so far for importing the list of files to be processed I have the following code
Dim files() As String = IO.Directory.GetFiles(txtfolderpath.Text)

For Each file As String In files

is there a way to restrict either the io.directory.get files method to only grab the details of files that have the extention.pdf.
or is there something simple i can add just after the "For file" line that basically checks the file extention of the file path and if its not a .pdf then allow me to throw up a message box saying something like "warning (file) is not a pdf this process should only be used for processing pdf files. please check the contents of the target folder and trying running again.

Path,GetFileExtension(f).Equals(".pdf", StringCompareOptions.NonCaseSensitive) -- something like this

Dim files() As String = IO.Directory.GetFiles(txtfolderpath.Text, "*.pdf")
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=net-8.0

@t.s if you add your first comment withIO.Directory.GetFiles(txtfolderpath.Text, "*.pdf") then I'd certainly mark it as the answer to my question. the existing question you've linked isn't as clear thas your comment pointing out that ,get files actually already has a built in parameter that can be used.

Matt, with all the respect, the question you asked is trivial and can be easily researched on microsoft site. If you know the deal, I would remove this question as it does not add to the knowledge due to its simplicity and commonality, Thanks.

If file.EndsWith(".pdf") Then
'your code here
End if
Next```
